# Why does css ":not()" not work when it has no parent selector?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Consider the following example:

```css
:not(p) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
   Red
</div>
<p>
  "p" why red?
</p>
```

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) `:not(p)` should select only the elements which are **not `p`**, but in my example it also selects `p`, why?

It might be said that `:not` is pseudo selector so it must be combined with another selector like `.test:not(p)`. Then why does the following work:

```css
  body :not(p) {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  Underlined, because I am not "p"
</div>
<p>
  test
</p>
```

Comment: html and body also match `:not(p)`. `color` is inherited.

Comment: Ok so it is inheriting, let me try with a different property.